# How to apply OTP in python

Tags: python, random, one-time-password

I am fairly new to programming and trying to create a program where a user get OTP by using random library and applies to log in to gain access of a file only if it match otherwise permission denied. Not sure what am I doing wrong here as it goes in infinite loop when I run.   Below is my code:

```
def rand_pass(size):
  

generate_pass=''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase+string.ascii_lowercase+string.digits)for n in range(size)])    
  return generate_pass 

OTP = rand_pass(10)
print('password:'+OTP)

Password = input('enter your OTP here:')

OTP = input('enter your OTP here:')
new_otp = "OTP"


OTP = new_otp
while OTP != "new_otp":
  print('Welcome')

  if OTP == "new_otp":
   print('welcome')
   break
  else:
    print('ACCESS DENIED.')
    continue
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are doing `new_otp = "OTP" and OTP = new_otp` and then you are checking that `while OTP != "new_otp"` So it will go in loop. because you are assigning `OTP` and checking `new-otp` Please check that logic

Comment: Your code has obvious indentation errors, but it is less obvious what the correct indentation should be. Please [edit] to fix this into valid Python syntax. In the desktop version of this site, you can simply paste your code, select the pasted block, and type ctrl-K to have it correctly marked up.

Comment: What is OTP? I suggest you learn the difference between a string value and a variable. It seems like you are trying to use strings as variable names which isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as per your requirement you can do as per below code. you just need to keep checking until user enters correct otp. if user enter wrong otp show ACCESS DENIED and ask again to enter otp

```
import random
import string

def rand_pass(size):
    generate_pass=''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase+string.ascii_lowercase+string.digits)for n in range(size)])    
    return generate_pass 

generated_otp = rand_pass(10)
print('new OTP :'+generated_otp)

while True:
    OTP = input('enter your OTP here:')
    if OTP == generated_otp:
        print('Correct OTP')
        break
    else:
        print('ACCESS DENIED.')
        continue
```

@GhostwhiteActualCompilers Please let me know if this is useful.